# What is the meaning of **Sample** in **Sample ACF**

Tags: autocorrelation

What is the meaning of **Sample** in **Sample ACF** (autocorrelation function)

Answer (score 5):

It's the empirical ACF computed using the sample.

Comment: @Mbaz: I'm not clear on why it's not an answer ? Maybe you want a formula.

Comment: Mark -- my mistake, I'm sorry. I have retracted the flag.

Comment: no problem. the formula has a denominator that is not trivial so I didn't remember it.